# i am receiving some unknown error after uploading image to the image folder (php)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image

I am creating question and answer system for my gaming tube . When I trying to upload an image to qstimages(image upload path folder name) something gone weird on question submitting page. look at the images i have poste.

[**this is image 1** - this is the normal condition before upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQBI1.png)

[**this is image 2** - after uploading the image sucessfully to image folder you can see the script is repeating the form again after advertisement the banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBSmt.png)

**this is the coding I have used for image upload function**

questionstart.php (html code)

```
<div class="container" id="contain">
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-8 content">
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="func/function.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <br />
    <label for="usr"> Ask anything about Games and Movies , Tv shows here : &nbsp; <span> Dont have an account , Post as a Guest </span> <?php //echo $pleasefill;?> </label>
    <input type="text" name="qst" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your question here " required/>

    <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="qsttextarea" rows="5" id="usr_dis" placeholder="Describe what is wrong ....."   onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.qsttextarea,this.form.countDisplay);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.qsttextarea,this.form.countDisplay);"  required></textarea>
     <hr>
      <div class="container" style="width: 100%;
                                    margin-left: -15px;
                                    border: 1px solid #e1e1e100;
                                    margin: 2px;
                                    background: #f1f1f1;
                                    padding-bottom: 10px;">
       <br />
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
       <br />
       <span id="uploaded_image"></span>
      </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="div_tablesplitter"> 
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="moreabout" class="form-control" id="more" placeholder="Give a short text about the questions" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Action    </option>
      <option value="saab"> Act-adven  </option>
      <option value="saab"> Adventure  </option>
      <option value="saab"> Role play  </option>
      <option value="saab"> Simulation </option>
      <option value="saab"> Strategy   </option>
      <option value="saab"> Sports     </option>
      <option value="saab"> Other      </option>
    </select>
    </select>

    <input readonly type="text" class="countDisplay" name="countDisplay" size="3" maxlength="3" value="3000"> 
    </div>
    </div>      
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit question" id="submit_button">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearText()" class="reset" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

js file linked to questionstart.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('change', '#file', function(){
  var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
  var form_data = new FormData();
  var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if(jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) 
  {
   alert("Invalid Image File");
  }
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
  var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;
  if(fsize > 5000000)
  {
   alert("Image File Size is very big");
  }
  else
  {
   form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url:"questionstart.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){
     $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
    },   
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
    }
   });
  }
 });
});
```

php code code included to questionstart.php

```
<?php
//upload.php
error_reporting(0);
if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $ext = end($test);
 $name = rand(100, 999) . '.' . $ext;
 $location = './qstimages/' . $name;  
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
 echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="100" width="100" class="img-thumbnail" />';
}
?>
```

**UPDATE (New Error)**

[when i refresh the page an error message shown , please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcKf.jpg)

Comment: sorry but what are we supposed to be looking for in those images?

Comment: hello question is updated please check it out @RamRider

Comment: Don't go live with this code your PHP code isn't secure.. Never trust javascript to allow file types.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland how can I secure the database. by the way, can I get an answer to my question?

Comment: OK - I think I can see what is going on. You are posting to the same page is that correct?

Comment: @RamRaider  yes, can you tell me how to avoid it ! is my code is correct? I  tried my best to fix it I got a new error. I have updated question please take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the server is responding to your ajax call with the form's html instead of the expected image html. Looking at your ajax call I think I see why. Should the url not be 'upload.php' instead of 'questionstart.php'?

```
   $.ajax({
    url:"upload.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){
     $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
    },   
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
    }
   });
```

Comment: you are right, how can I prevent it  is there any method ?

Comment: Yes, there are likely myriad methods to prevent it. However, we can't help if we don't have enough information. What's this image_upload.php file in the latest error? I don't see the code for it or how it relates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are posting ( via ajax ) to the same page but you are not isolating the portion of code that processes the upload from the rest of the php script that runs whenever the page loads so in effect the ajax query is loading the entire page and sending all the generated HTML content as the response whereas you want to return data specific to the image upload only.

For you the important bit of the below code should be the top portion where there is firstly a logic test to check the request is POST ( can add more stringent logic tests for other POST fields too I suggest )- but then flush the buffers of any previously generated content ( if there is any before this point ) - process the upload and then `EXIT` / `DIE` to cease loading the remainder of the HTML content.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
        /* 
            ensure that the response sent back to the ajax callback is 
            ONLY the data you want to send and not the entire page!
        */

        # Flush the output buffers
        ob_clean();


        /*
            This is where you would process the image upload
        */


        /* Whatever data you need to send back to the ajax callback */
        echo $response;


        #EXIT to ensure response data is only generated here
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> - question start - </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- html content -->
        <!--

            The html content includes the form and all
            other page elements which are being repeated
            after the ajax request has been sent.

        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you write down the code it bit confusing for me, and I have received an error but its okay I can use error_reporting(0) to clear the error. please write down the code its a big help . @RamRaider thanks

Comment: The code posted in the question is disjointed in that you have posted pieces  but not the entire page/script which in turns makes it harder to positively provide a solution. You could make a pastebin dump and share the link or update the question with the full code? In essence though if you are posting to the same page then you should isolate that portion of code that is processed by ajax as I did here. If you are posting to a different page/script then it might not be such an issue